# How to find the angular momentum of two rods of different lengths and masses attached to each other by one end?

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

The image attached shows the system in question. The arrow represents the direction of motion. The body is traveling in uniform motion. How would one find the angular momentum at the end of the second rod? I am unsure as to how you would find the moment of inertia for this system which could then be used to calculate the angular momentum.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $m_2$ remains parallel with $m_1$, then the angular velocity (ω) at the end of the second rod would be the same as the rest of the system.  To find the angular momentum of $m_2$ relative to the axle, you add the angular momentum associated with the motion of its center of mass [$m_2$(rω)r] to its angular momentum about its center of mass (Iω). (The r is the distance from the axle to the center of $m_2$, and I is the moment of inertia of $m_2$ about its center.) Or, you can treat the system as one rod, find the angular momentum, and then subtract the angular momentum of $m_1$.